# Exiting fullscreen leaves the app blank

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

When I exit a fullscreen video in my webview the application goes blank and just displays the background. I'm at a loss and can't seem to fix my error, it was completely fine until I lost track and forgot to check my code regularly. Can someone help solve my problem and describe what I have done. I've never used stackOverFlow so thanks to anyone for your help.

Java

```
superWebView = (VideoEnabledWebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);
    ViewGroup videoLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.videoLayout); // Your own view, read class comments
    webChromeClient = new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient(nonVideoLayout, videoLayout, superWebView) // See all available constructors...
    {

    };
    webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
        {
            // code to handle the full-screen change, showing and hiding
            if (fullscreen)
            {
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                backNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forwardNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                refreshNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homeNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                searchNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                superWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    });


    superWebView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
}
```

XML

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mySwipeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/browserlite_back"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mFullscreenContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- View that will be shown while the fullscreen video loads (maybe include a spinner and a "Loading..." message) -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchBar_Background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:autofillHints="@android:string/autofill"
            android:background="@drawable/round_searchbar"
            android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:hint="Search or Enter URL"
            android:inputType="none|text|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete|textUri"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:textColor="#656565"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchBar_Background"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonWeather"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="Weather" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNews"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="News" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDDG"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
            android:text="DDG" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.okaybrowser.okaybrowserfastprivate.VideoEnabledWebView
        android:id="@+id/mWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchBar_Background"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:contextClickable="true">

    </com.okaybrowser.okaybrowserfastprivate.VideoEnabledWebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff00fe"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/videoLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/backNav"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/forwardNav"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeNav"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_home_grey_24dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refreshNav"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_refresh_grey_24dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchNav"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_search_grey_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#273238"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Can you show a picture of how that happens?

Comment: Try debugging your code. Is your else block executing when exiting full screen mode ?

Comment: Try to replace `.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE );` to `.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in VideoEnabledWebChromeClient
It helped me

Comment: @RahulChokshi Didn't work for me

Comment: @UmangBurman what do you mean?

Comment: @Pokimaen I meant it will be better if you can post a picture of what exactly is happening.. So that we can understand your problem better.

Comment: @UmangBurman Not much to show, the app shows widgets, I enter a video in fullscreen from my webview, when I exit fullscreen the app then shows the background with no webview or widgets. The navigation menu is visible but doesn't work.

Comment: maybe thats bcoz you are making everything GONE here: searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                backNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forwardNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                refreshNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homeNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                searchNav.setVisibility(View.GONE); and not making it visible again..

Comment: @UmangBurman I tried changing it but still the same results no matter what.

Comment: @Pokimaen Why don't you use another activity to play only your video in WebView. Then, when your video is done, finish the activity. By doing that you can have everything going well. You don't have to worry about VISIBILITY too..

Comment: @UmangBurman thanks for your help, I guess that would be the best option, I never had this issue before and wanted to keep it in the same activity. Thanks and sorry for your time.

Comment: @Pokimaen Hey shall I post this as an answer, So that you can accept and upvote the same?

Comment: @UmangBurman I'm new to this site so I have no idea what you just said lol

Comment: @Pokimaen lol.. I'll Post my comment as a answer, there will be a tick mark there, just click it.. :) okay?

Comment: @Pokimaen I've posted my answer :)

Comment: @Pokimaen Thanks, Happy Coding.. See ya

Comment: @UmangBurman Isn't that sort of cheating because we never actually solved it lol

Comment: hahaha... Atleast an alternate solution.. :D But this idea also does what you want .. :P

Comment: @UmangBurman haha alright, see you.

Comment: @Pokimaen Oh and one more thing, If someone gives you an answer with a same as exactly what you were looking for then please accept his answer instead.. so that others would know.. See ya.. take care..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

Why don't you use another activity to play only your video in WebView as FullScreen. Then, when your video is done, finish the activity. By doing that you can have everything going well. You don't have to worry about VISIBILITY too..

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**

```
webChromeClient.setOnToggledFullscreen(new VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.ToggledFullscreenCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
    {
        // code to handle the full-screen change, showing and hiding
        if (fullscreen)
        {
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                backNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                forwardNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                refreshNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                homeNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                searchNav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                backNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                forwardNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                refreshNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                homeNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bottomNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchNav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
                }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Same result, perhaps it's my xml?